# is using angular-cli.json the preferred way to add 3rd party scripts (into your Angular apps)?

Tags: angular, hammer.js

Is this

```
`<script src="../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"></script>`
```

or this

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
  ]`
```

method a better way to include scripts into your Angular App?

Comment: Both ways are wrong. Use `import Hammer from 'hammerjs';`

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-5-gesture-support  even has a 4th way?

Comment: That one is wrong as well :p

Comment: Could you pls give the reasons or point to some resource for us to know more, why these are wrong and `import Hammer from 'hammerjs'` is the correct way. It's frustrating to see the 3 examples I showed are widely spread but yet, they do not seem to be the right ones. WHAT's the Diff among these anyway?

Comment: Global variables are bad that's the argument. You should be processing these dependencies through your loader so that they can register themselves as modules if designed to do so. Bypassing your loader means that you are losing out on the advantages of using modules while paying all of the complexity costs. What's the point of a complex tool chain built around shimming ECMAScript modules if you don't use them?